# Is this a valid binary tree?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

I've just learnt that there are 3 types of binary tree: complete, full and degenerate.

However, for this tree below, it doesn't quite fulfil the characteristics of the 3 types I've listed above.

Can there be such binary trees?

```
           18
              \  
               30  
               /  \
             50   40
            /  \  /  \
           60  70 55  77
```

Comment: "Tree terminology is not well-standardized and so varies in the literature.": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a valid binary tree?

Yes it is.

The definition in [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) is:

"In computer science, a binary tree is a tree data structure in which each node has at most two children, which are referred to as the left child and the right child.", which your tree satisfies.

PS: This tree is not complete, not full and not degenerate.

Answer (score 2):

This tree is not complete, full or degenerate. It is simply a binary tree that doesn't fit in those categories. 
Yes there can be such binary trees as these, though of any type of balanced tree (AVL, Red-Black, etc) would look nothing like this